# Overwrite mat-icon with custom icon

Tags: angular, angular-material

is it possible to overwrite the icon being used by mat-icon. For example the element

```
<mat-icon>cloud_upload</mat-icon>
```

would render the default material icon but I need a different icon (svg) for the same name `cloud_upload`.

Why do I want that: I'm working with libraries that contain the mat-icon and by default, the material icon should be shown. But the library can be used in another app that requires a different icon.
My naive idea was, just tell mat-icon to use a different icon for the name e.g. `cloud_upload`. I was looking into `MatIconRegistry` but I think, I can't overwrite the default icons there, at least I found no way yet.

Thanks for any help. And maybe my approach is not ideal and there's a different way to fulfil the requirements.

Comment: What you're trying to do feels hacky to say the least. Your best bet would be to contact the author of the library so that icon properties are somehow exposed. As a workaround, you could download the material icons font, replace the icons you want changed, and self-host it yourself instead of pulling it from CDN. I guess that should work, as long as you provide the correct name in the `@font-face` declaration.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. I looked into the source code of mat-icon and it's just not made for this kind of customizing (I can fully understand that). Looks like using an own, "patched" icon font is a solution, although it's quite cumbersome.